# Read binary attachment data from a SOAP response

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, c#-4.0

I'm getting Soap+XMl response from external web service. I have used HttpClient POST request. I found same question for some other platform I have attached the link here. Same type of response I'm getting from webservice. So I want to read binary value and I need to create files accordingly.
[enter link description here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BLxCIAW)

Comment: The link is the output of a sniffer that is displaying the pdf which is an attachment.  To read the binary you have to find the tag that contains the attachment and save the byte[] to a stream.  The binary is probably a  Base 64 string and you need to use Convert.FromBase64String(string) to get the byte[].

Answer (score 0):

There are three basic options for soap attachment：SwA（SOAP with Attachments）,DIME（Direct Internet Message Encapsulation）,MTOM（Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism）,MTOM based on XOP（XML-Binary OPtimized Packaging）.MTOM is used in the link you gave.To send or receive binary attachments using MTOM in WCF, you only need to set the value of messageencoding to MTOM in the binding:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgFCW.png)

The following link is a demo:
https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/mtom-encoding?redirectedfrom=MSDN

If your service is a web service, you need to get the WSDL of the web service, and then call the service according to the proxy generated by the WSDL.